# second virtualhost causes apache2 failure

Tags: apache-httpd

This on a Raspberry Pi 2.
When I add a second virtual host to the 000-default.conf file, and restart apache2, it gives me this error:

```
[....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
failed!
```

When I run `systemctl status apache2.service`, it gives me

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-09-05 22:52:11 MDT; 2min 34s ago
Process: 584 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

My 000-default.conf file (first virtual host works just fine by-itself):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /home/pi/public_html
         #LogLevel info ssl:warn                                                                                          

         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
         ServerName alexspi2.local
         ServerAdmin (email address, not shown for privacy)
         DocumentRoot /home/pi/public_html
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
         SSLEngine on
         SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ss1/ca.crt
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ca.key
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I don't know what is wrong with the second part.

Comment: Can you add more details from /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: I think this question is better off in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a different conf file for the second virtualhost and put it in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

and run

```
$ sudo a2ensite
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

1. will enable the new conf file
2. will enable rewrite module to allow filepath access
3. restart apache

Also

> apachectl -t

to check for config syntax

Comment: The last part was useful. Turns out that the virtual host pointed to a directory for the keys that didn't exist. (Accidentally put a 1 where there should be a L).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should troubleshot the the problem by analyzing the:

- output of `journalctl -xn`
- output of `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=apache2.service`
- the log file as @Varad A.G. suggested

Your second `<virtualhost>`section which matches for 443 Port should be supported by a global `Listen [IP:]443`directive too. In default, apache already has `Listen 80` global directive within main configuration, that is why the first one works.

And also as @Cunningham's Lawyer stated, that question should be asked to Server Fault